# f1 score for test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

To get the best f1 score of cross validation I do that

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, cv=10, verbose=10, scoring='f1')
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("best parameters", grid_search.best_params_)
print('Best score : {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_))
```

but for the Test score I also need f1-score not the accuracy

```
print("Test Score",grid_search.best_estimator_.score(X_test,y_test.reshape(y_test.shape[0])))
```

Is there any function e.g., `f1_score()` that I can use or should I write the function myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the f1 score with:

- the `classification report`
  ([example here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html))
- the Scikit-learn f1_score function:
  (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html)